# How to create a subset of a dataframe with certain values in a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to create a subset of a dataframe based on multiple values found in a column. The column is 'tencode_desc' and the values that I want to select for are:

"Holdup / Robbery", "Bank Robbery", "Burglary Residence", "Burglary -
    Non-Residence", "Theft"

I have tried to make a new variable with those strings, and then use the .isin function with the column

```
df.columns

Index(['id', 'call_time', 'complaint_id', 'shift', 'tencode', 'tencode_desc','disposition', 'disposition_desc', 'unit', 'sector', 'zone', 'lat','lng'],dtype='object')
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
tencode_filter = ['Holdup / Robbery', 'Bank Robbery', 'Burglary Residence', 'Burglary - Non-Residence', 'Theft']

df.loc[df['call_time'].isin(tencode_filter)]
```

I'm receiving this error
`ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Holdup / Robbery')`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
df = df[df.tencode_desc.str.contains('|'.join(tenecode_filter))]
```

To join your options into a regular expression. You may need to escape the special characters like `'/'` you are using. Such as

```
tencode_filter = ['Holdup \/ Robbery', 'Bank Robbery', 'Burglary Residence', 'Burglary - Non-Residence', 'Theft'].
```